# How to set a boolean value in Firebase DB in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app i want to track user activities like login, logout for this i want to store a node with boolean data type, so how do I set the boolean value (true or false) from my application ?

Comment: Did you link your android project with the Firebase project?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please responde with @.

Comment: Yes i have connected my app to firebase @ronginat

Comment: I have studied various documents on firebase authenticatiom but i need boleen values for other activities, i tried using integer 0,1 but boleen is much easier as compared to @Alex Mamo

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to check out Firebase Documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup and in particular https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users ! Using firebase login you can check the current user with

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```

instead of creating a db node for this, as described in Firebase documentation.

Comment: I can use this to track user login logout but no other things for which i will need boolean vales

Comment: First of all, next time you have to make your question more clear, because if you describe your problem well we can help you find a better way or answer with exactly you are searching, anyway, Firebase offers you https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write to understand how to add and check value on your db, it would be useless if I should re-write what is perfectly described in the documentation. Just try and ask what you don't understand about it! If you wanna develop an app how can you do it without understand how your db works